# Implement v. Extends in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Beginner in Typescript.

Question: Unsure of when to use `implements` v. `extends` when using es6 classes. when we have an interface that **only** contains properties?

```js
interface UserProps {
  name: string,
  address: string,
  phone: number,
}

class User (extends or implements) UserProps {

  constructor(props: UserProps) {
    this.name = props.name;
    this.address = props.address;
    this.phone = props.phone;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes implement interfaces. Classes extend classes. Interfaces extend interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Think of "extends" as inheritance syntax. Class Employee extends Person {}; You're gaining the properties and methods of the Parent class as long as they're not private.

"implements" is like.. class Person adheres to the structure of interface IPerson.